# Javascript function refuses to calculate variables

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling, dom-events

I am trying to allow Javascript to calculate a function of several different variables and results. Honestly I've spent the last two days working on it and literally have no idea where to go from here. My code as follows:

```
<html>
<title>Calculate Your Monthly Payments</title> 
        <script language = "JavaScript"> 
            function Calc(){ 
            var a, res;             
            a = parseFloat(document.monthly.form.value); 
            res1 = a/1000;
            res2 = a/500;
            res3 = a/300;

            if(document.monthly.payments[1].style.visibility = "visible" )
                window.alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £" + res1);

            else if(document.monthly.payments[2].style.visibility = "visible" )
                window.alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £ " + res2);

            else(document.monthly.payments[3].style.visibility = "visible" )
                window.alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £ " + res3);
            } 

        </script> 
</head> 


<div id="container">

        <h2>Calculate Your Monthly Payments</h2> 
        <h4>Please fill in the form below</h4>
         <form name = "monthly"> 
           How much are you borrowing? (£): <br><input name = "form" type = "text" size = 10 id="textarea"> <br><br>

                Mortgage Type: <br>
                <select name = "payments">
                  <option value="" selected>Please Select </option>
                  <option value="1">Mortgage 2.19% fixed until 2015 </option>
                  <option value="2">Mortgage 3.17% fixed until 2017 </option>
                  <option value="3">Mortgage 3.18% fixed until 2024 </option>
                </select>
                <br><br>                

           <input type = "button" value = "Calculate Payments! " onclick = "Calc();"> 
        </form>
</div>
</html>
```

I have been trying to have the event being displayed as a popup which says 
 "Your Monthly Payment is ...".
The equation I want to implement should work as whatever you enter is divided by what you choose.

If a is selected then as an example it will be divided by 1000 
if b is selected then as an example it will be divided by 500 
and if c is selected then as an example it will be divided by 300.

**However.. none of this works.**

I have been going though the code over and over and have made it work, though only partially as the event then displays two pop-ups. First being option value 1 and second replacing it after being click with option value 2.

**The Problem is that:**

Upon viewing in a browser and clicking on the "Calculate Payments" button nothing happens. Why is this?

---

I hope I made this clear since I'm a bit rough with English but I would appreciate any help whatsoever.

Comment: -1 for not identifying the *actual* problem.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea:  `name="form"`... not only is it confusing to assign the name `form` to your field, `form` might be a restricted word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works - try it.

```
<html>
<title>Calculate Your Monthly Payments</title> 
        <script language = "JavaScript"> 
            function Calc(){ 
            var a, res;             
            a = parseFloat(document.monthly.form.value); 
            res1 = a/1000;
            res2 = a/500;
            res3 = a/300;

            if(document.monthly.payments.value == "1" )
            {
                window.alert("Your monthlys repayments have been estimaded to be £" + res1);
            }
            else if(document.monthly.payments.value == "2" )
            {
                window.alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £ " + res2);
            }
            else if(document.monthly.payments.value == "3" )
            {
                window.alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £ " + res3);
            } 
        }
        </script> 
</head> 


<div id="container">

        <h2>Calculate Your Monthly Payments</h2> 
        <h4>Please fill in the form below</h4>
         <form name = "monthly"> 
           How much are you borrowing? (£): <br><input name = "form" type = "text" size = 10 id="textarea"> <br><br>

                Mortgage Type: <br>
                <select name = "payments">
                  <option value="" selected>Please Select </option>
                  <option value="1">Mortgage 2.19% fixed until 2015 </option>
                  <option value="2">Mortgage 3.17% fixed until 2017 </option>
                  <option value="3">Mortgage 3.18% fixed until 2024 </option>
                </select>
                <br><br>                

           <input type = "button" value = "Calculate Payments! " onclick = "Calc();"> 
        </form>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Jatin, wow I'm actually surprised at how much of the original script you managed to maintain but still fix it. I was playing around with it for a bit and see that instead of visibility function you opted to remove it altogether. This is Ideally what I was looking for so in that case I think you deserved it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the following lines of your code need to be looked into check the payments array

```
        if(document.monthly.payments[101].style.visibility = "visible" )
            window.alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £" + res1);

        else if(document.monthly.payments[102].style.visibility = "visible" )
            window.alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £ " + res2);

        else(document.monthly.payments[103].style.visibility = "visible" )
            window.alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £ " + res3);
```

Check This Out

```
        if(document.monthly.payments.style.visibility = "visible" )
            window.alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £" + res1);

        else if(document.monthly.payments.style.visibility = "visible" )
            window.alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £ " + res2);

        else(document.monthly.payments.style.visibility = "visible" )
            window.alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £ " + res3);
        }
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I just saw that as well. I actually thought the arrays was the problem so I was playing around with it so that was actually meant to be 1,2,and3 not 101,102,103. But yep I have made the changes and unfortunately still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

1) Download firebug. Or turn on javascript debugging in whatever browser you are using. It will show that you have an error. The reason why "nothing happens" is that processing stops after this error. `document.monthly.payments[101]`? What is 101? Not sure what you were going for here.

2) You have `else(document.monthly.payments[103].style.visibility = "visible" )`

you can't have else(condition). it should just be else {...}

3) Try this:

```
  if(document.monthly.payments.selectedIndex == 1)
                window.alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £" + res1);

            else if(document.monthly.payments.selectedIndex == 2 )
                window.alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £ " + res2);

            else if(document.monthly.payments.selectedIndex == 3 )
                window.alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £ " + res3);
            }
```

Your function could also look like this:

```
function Calc(){ 
            if (document.monthly.payments.selectedIndex == 0){
                alert("Please select a mortgage type");
                return;
            }

            var mortgages = [1000,500,300];
            window.alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £" + (parseFloat(document.monthly.form.value) / mortgages[document.monthly.payments.selectedIndex-1])  );
            }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I am actually doing this in dreamweaver and am testing the code in Google Chrome 19 and FireFox 10. And the whole 101 thing was just me testing out different values since I had no idea what the issue was but thanks I will try your code and report back. Thanks

Comment: @Nikolas, in Chrome hit F12 and you'll see the console pop up with the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript doesnt seem to make any sense, and happens to expose some not very good practices. It sounds like you simply want to alert a different value based on the option you select in your drop down. In that case, you would be better served to insert a script like this:

```
<select id="mySelect">
   <!-- Options -->
</select>

<script>
     var selectElement = document.getElementById('mySelect');

     if(selectElement != null)
     {
         selectElement.addEventListener('change', function()
         {
             var selectedOptionValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

             switch(selectedOptionValue)
             {
                 case 1: // Do Stuff
                    break;
                 case 2: // Do Stuff
                    break;
                 default: // Do Stuff
                    break;
             }
         });
     }
</script>
```

This way, you determine the value on the click event in an unobtrusive way, and you can then provide code as needed to show the alert.

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/DTTg5/6/ )

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function calculate()
    { 
        var payments = parseInt( document.getElementById("payments").value );
        var a = parseFloat( document.getElementById("borrowing").value );

        var res1 = a/1000;
        var res2 = a/500;
        var res3 = a/300;

        if ( payments  == 1 )
        {
            alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £" + res1);
        }
        else if ( payments  == 2 )
        {
            alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £ " + res2);
        }
        else if ( payments  == 3 )
        {
            alert("Your monthly repayments have been estimaded to be £ " + res3);
        }
    } 

</script> 

<form name = "monthly"> 
    How much are you borrowing? (£):
    <br/>
    <input name="form" type="text" size="10" id="borrowing"/>
    <br/><br/>
    Mortgage Type:
    <br/>
    <select name="payments" id="payments">
      <option value="0" selected>Please Select </option>
      <option value="1">Mortgage 2.19% fixed until 2015 </option>
      <option value="2">Mortgage 3.17% fixed until 2017 </option>
      <option value="3">Mortgage 3.18% fixed until 2024 </option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>                
    <input type="button" value="Calculate Payments!" onclick="calculate();"> 
</form>
```

​

Answer (score 0):

```
        var a, res;             
        a = parseFloat(document.monthly.form.value); 
        res1 = a/1000;
        res2 = a/500;
        res3 = a/300;
```

Better, defensive coding:

```
        var a;             //declare only one variable on a line
        a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("borrowing").value) ;
        if (isNaN(a)) {
           alert("please enter nn.nn");
           return;
        } 
        var res1 = a/1000;
        var res2 = a/500;
        var res3 = a/300;
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks I wasn't familiar with this but I tried it out as well and it prefer it to what I had previously. I will definitely be recording it for future use. Really appreciate it.